# C++ check if element is std::vector

Tags: c++, types, vector

i would like to iterate through a vector and check if elements are vectors or strings. Also i need a way to pass different vecors to a function.
Something like this:

```
using namespace std;
string toCustomString(<some vector> vec) {
    string ret = "";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.length(); ++i) 
        if (vec[i] == %vector%)
            ret += toCustomString(vec[i]);
        else //if type of vec[i] is string
            ret += "foo"+vec[i]+"bar";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

- Well, first i need to know how i can check correctly if vec[i] is a std::vector
- Then i need to know how to define the paramater for the function to accept any kind of (multidimensional) vector

Comment: Look up Runtime Type Identification (RTTI) and `typeid` keyword

Comment: A C++ `std::vector` can contain only items of one static type: every element of a `vector<string>` will be a string, every element of `vector<vector<T> >` will be a `vector<T>`.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you would do in a dynamically-typed language. This is going to be very complicated to do in a language like C++ that has static-typing. Post what you are actually trying to accomplish and someone might be able to suggest a solution that will work in a statically-typed language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector` can only contain one type - that is the `T` in `std::vector<T>`, which can be accessed with the member `value_type`.

What you probably are looking for is template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
string toCustomString(std::vector<T> vec) {
    // general case
}

template<>
string toCustomString<std::string>(std::vector<std::string> vec) {
    // strings
}
```

(if you want to partially specialize it over all vectors then you'll need to lift it to a struct)

If you really want to store both strings and vectors in the vector then look at Boost.Variant and Boost.Any

Answer (score 2):

Generally, your `<some vector> vec` would have type *either* `vector<string>` *or* `vector<vector<string>>`, for example.

In order to declare the variable, you need its type, and its type also specifies exactly what it stores.

Now, you can work around this using [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant.html) (or roll your own discriminated union), like so:

```
typedef boost::variant<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> Vec_of_StringOrVec;
```

but Dirk Holsopple is right that this isn't idiomatic C++, and you may be better off looking for a different approach.

Comment: There's in principle nothing to say against discriminated unions. I wouldn't call them "not idiomatic" for C++, either. Proper "closed" algebraic datatypes have their value in any language; in OO languages it may be more idiomatic to use derived instances of a common base class, but that's not always optimal.

Comment: True - I guess I mean that non-inheritance-based runtime polymorphism isn't very C++ish ... it's more usual to choose compile-time polymorphism for unrelated types, and/or virtual dispatch for runtime. There's nothing wrong with it, but from the question I can't tell whether a more idiomatic alternative is available

Answer (score 0):

As everyone says, vectors in C++ only hold one type. There's no need or point in checking the type of each element in turn, which is just as well because there's no way to do that. What you do instead is overload the function on the type of the argument. Something like this:

```
string toCustomString(const string &str) {
    return "foo" +str + "bar";
}

template <typename T>
string toCustomString(const std::vector<T> &vec) {
    string ret;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) 
        ret += toCustomString(vec[i]);
    return ret;
}
```

Now, if someone passes a `vector<string>` into `toCustomString` then the call `toCustomString(vec[i])` will select the `toCustomString(const string &str)` overload.

If someone passes a `vector<int>` into `toCustomString` then the code won't compile, because there is (currently) no `toCustomString(int)` overload[*].

If someone passes a `vector<vector<string>>` to `toCustomString` then `toCustomString(vec[i])` will pass a `vector<string>`, see above.

In all three cases, *different* `toCustomString` functions are called. In the first case it's `toCustomString<string>(const vector<string>&)`, which is a different instantiation of the `toCustomString` template from the third case, `toCustomString<vector<string>>(const vector<vector<string>>&)`. The middle case tries to instantiate `toCustomString<int>`, but fails because `toCustomString(v[i])` doesn't match any function it knows about.

All of this is determined at compile time. The point of templates is to create multiple functions (or classes) with particular differences between them. In this case the difference is the type of vector passed in.

[*] This seems in line with your claim that `vec[i]` must be *either* a vector *or* a string, not any third option. If you wanted for example the return value for a `vector<something_else>` to be empty, then you could add a catch-all template:

```
template <typename T> 
string toCustomString(const T &) { 
    return string(); 
}
```

and of course you can add more overloads for any other types you want to handle.